# Optimizing PostgreSQL SIMILAR TO command after getting "ERROR: The regular expression provided produced excessive matches"

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I'm trying to search through a bunch of strings 100's-1000's of characters and a few million database rows to find a pattern of some text followed by a colon, new line, and at least one character more of text:

```
SOME TEXT:
MORE TEXT
```

I want to make sure I don't accidentally catch text where the line ends in emoticons such as `(:`. Currently I'm using trying to use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM reviews
WHERE reviews.comment SIMILAR TO '%[^(]:[' + chr(10) + chr(13) + ']_%'
```

When I run this, I get:

```
ERROR: The regular expression provided produced excessive matches
```

How can I restructure this query to more accurately reflect what I've outlined above? Done properly I don't think this should be very computationally intensive, I just assume that the `%[^(]` at the beginning is causing the parser to do a lot more work than it should.

Comment: I know in mysql for fulltext search if the results are>50% table they are ignored.Are you sure this is not some sort of postgres equivalent?That is, the query is not that intensive but it actually returns too many results.Talking out of my behind on this one.

Comment: Interesting insight, but I don't think that is the case here. In a more general query `reviews.comment SIMILAR TO '%:[' + chr(10) + chr(13) + ']%'` I got back < 10% of the table.

Comment: When did PostgreSQL start allowing you to use `+` with strings?

Answer (score 0):

Not being as familiar myself with the SQL standard regular expression implementation (which is what is used by `SIMILAR TO`), I would say you can do what you want with the POSIX regular expression `[^(]:\s*[\r\n]\S` (the POSIX operators for positive match against an expression are `~` and `~*` for case sensitivity and case insensitivity respectively).

For example, some silly test data:

```
postgres=# SELECT id, data FROM foo ORDER BY id;
 id |              data          
----+--------------------------------
  1 | this string has:              +
    | more than one line
  2 | this is just one line
  3 | this string has an emoticon (:+
    | and then some other stuff
  4 | ANOTHER STRING THAT:          +
    | HAS MORE THAN ONE LINE
  5 | A multi-line string           +
    | that has no colon
(5 rows)
```

(Note that the `+` characters appear to just be the `psql` client's representation of a newline character in the middle of a string.)

And using that regular expression as a filter:

```
postgres=# SELECT id, data FROM foo WHERE data ~* '[^(]:\s*[\r\n]\S';
 id |          data      
----+------------------------
  1 | this string has:      +
    | more than one line
  4 | ANOTHER STRING THAT:  +
    | HAS MORE THAN ONE LINE
(2 rows)
```

And the query returns only the multi-line strings which fit the pattern (while excluding the string that contained the emoticon).

Do note that the expression above permits white space between the colon and the line break - you could remove the `\s*` if that is not desirable.